# Simulating Random Vector X in R to Confirm with Example that cov(AX) = A cov(X) A'

Tags: r, random-variable, linear-algebra

As has been answered previously, the proof of `cov(AX)  = A cov(X) A'` with `X` being  a random vector and `A` a fixed matrix is relatively straightforward [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106199/why-covax-a-covx-a).

In order to get a more visual sense of random vectors, I was trying to "proof" this equality to myself by generating random data in `R`, like this:

```
    set.seed(0)
    a <- c(rnorm(1e6,6,3))
    b <- c(rnorm(1e6,11,8))
    X <- rbind(a,b)
    A <- matrix(c(9, 100, 20, 200), nrow=2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   20
[2,]  100  200
```

From there, calculating the $RHS$ of the equality is probably the result of:

```
A %*% cov(t(X)) %*% t(A)
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  26346.71  264277.7
[2,] 264277.71 2651783.0
```

The question is how to calculate the $LHS$ of the equation.

Comment: So is your question how to multiply each row of `X` by `A`? If so, consider if you can take some transposes to get what you want....

Comment: Yes,that is the question.

Comment: I think I got it. I would really appreciate if you could verify that I did it correctly. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Dougal's suggestion, I used the transposed to solve the computation bypassing a `Reached total allocation of 3978Mb: see help(memory.size)` initial message the same way I did on the calculation for the $RHS$ of the equation.

On the $RHS$ instead of calculating `A %*% cov(X) %*% t(A)` , which was giving me a similary memory problem, I calculated `A %*% cov(t(X)) %*% t(A)`, which I hope is exactly the same, `cov(X) = cov(t(X))`, even though I haven't been able to conclusively verify it.

On the $LHS$ I went about as: `cov(t(A%*%X))` with the identical result as before.

The fact that in both cases I'm getting:

```
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  26346.71  264277.7
[2,] 264277.71 2651783.0
```

is promising, but I'd welcome feedback as to the correctness of the linear algebra, possibly moving back this part as an edit to the original question.